# Cannot find llc tool in LLVM

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I can get llvm-ir from C code using Clang. I just want to work with LLVM-IR. For my compiler project.
I need to convert LLVM-IR to target machine code or executable.

But I can't convert LLVM-IR to .exe. I downloaded LLVM from official site. But I can't find llc or lli tool. Did I download the wrong one?. I use windows 10.

Comment: Perhaps you'd better ask a TA or another student to check your computer and what you've downloaded. As it stands, you're asking people who have no access to your computer why an unknown variant (source? binaries? which site do you think is "the official"?) of an unknown version (9? head?) doesn't work for you. (It does work for me, BTW.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, there is no `llc.exe` in Windows binary package. Compile LLVM yourself, this is pretty [straightforward](http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html).